# What happens on operating system-level if a software throws an exception?

Tags: cpu, java, process

In high-level programming languages (for example Java) you have the concept of exceptions.

These exceptions can be either implicit or explicit thrown. After an exception has been thrown it can be catched in some special error-handling branch.

Now I'm wondering:
What happens there under the hood?

What is an exception for the operating system?

How is an exception "caught"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Information from MSDN: [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680657(v=vs.85).aspx)

Exceptions are similar to interrupts handled by the CPU. When a exception occurs, be it software or hardware, your processor will stop execution and transfers control to the system. The system saves the current thread state and information of the exception. It then tries to find a handler. This is essentially how it is "Caught".

The order for finding a handler is:

- A Debugger attached to the program
- Find a frame based exception handler (Language specific)
- Ask the Debugger again
- If its not being debugged, or the debugger doesnt handle the exception the OS will provide its default handling. For most exceptions the default action is to call ExitProcess.

If its kernel-mode code (Operating system) then it tries to find an exception handler. If there isn't one, or the one available doesn't handle that particular exception then ExitWindows function is called. Brownie points if you can guess what that does.

In other words, its your high level language that deals with exceptions, the OS just provides the option of last resort.